# Clustering signals in my computer program, what approach would be best?

Tags: signal-processing, clustering

This is a programming/algorithm question, but mathematical insights would probably be very handy.

In essence I have 2000 arrays of electrical power output data, each consisting of around 20-40 positive integer entries. Most often they are in a certain bandwidth, say between 20,000 and 30,000:

[20131 22302 24300 .....]

[27000 28030 300000 .....]

each array is a power output spike where each number is milliwatts and represents a data at a certain 'second in time', so 10 entries would mean 10 seconds of measurements.

What I am interested in is somehow clustering these arrays by a computer program. Some of them are in the same sort of range and it would be nice to recognise patterns, where i can 'bucket' the arrays and then eventually label them as belonging to the same category.

I think this can potentially be solved by unsupervised machine learning algorithms, but i wonder if that would be the best way.

I am a programmer, and I could come up with some possible solutions, but I feel those might be a bit naive.

Any pointers/approaches/strategies would be appreciated!

Comment: [Principle Component Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) could be a first step. If not all arrays have the same length then you could use sliding windows to form the input set. Dimension $20$ is low enough to do this without too many other tricks.

Comment: You may want to ask on stats.stackexchange.com instead.